# How to sum the first values of a groupby result and write this as a df column across the relevant group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analysis

I have a data frame looking like this (please see below):

```
Player Name         Team                    PlayerMarketValue

Steph Curry         Golden State Warriors   169027.4782
Steph Curry         Golden State Warriors   169027.4782
Steph Curry         Golden State Warriors   169027.4782
Steph Curry         Golden State Warriors   169027.4782
Lebron James        All Stars               120896.3772
Lebron James        All Stars               120896.3772
Lebron James        All Stars               120896.3772
Luka Doncic         All Stars               36789.6562
Luka Doncic         All Stars               36789.6562
Luka Doncic         All Stars               36789.6562
```

I am trying to find a good way to groupby both `Team` and then `PlayerName` and from this, take the first instance of `PlayerMarketValue` and then sum this and write this value across its respective `Team`.

I've hit the block after getting to:

```py
NBAData['TotalTeamVal'] = NBAData.groupby(['Team', 'Player Name'])['PlayerMarketValue'].first().sum()
```

Ie: I am looking for (note the `All Stars` rows in particular):

[image]

Comment: Please copy/paste data as text.

Comment: could you please clarify why you are you choosing the first row? Is there any particular criterion or just because you need one of the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing much about the structure of the data, I will assume that a player can only be part in one of the teams, thus I would start

1. remove the duplicate rows associated with each player
2. sum the values of players on a team
3. reset the index and merge all back to the main `DataFrame` using the team columns as a key

```
pd.merge(df, 
         df.drop_duplicates('Player Name').groupby(['Team'])['PlayerMarketValue'].sum().reset_index(), 
         on='Team', 
         suffixes= ['', '_Team']
         )
```

Comment: Thank-you for your input - this was very concise and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby team on the new dataframe, get the total value and merge back:

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['Player Name', 'Team'])
           .PlayerMarketValue.first()
           .groupby(['Team']).sum(),
         left_on='Team',
         right_index=True,
         suffixes=('','Total')
)
```

Comment: Why not use groupby transform? Am I missing something

Comment: Transform on which groupby?

Comment: or why to `groupby` twice, when you just want to drop the duplicates...?

Comment: @user7440787 that’s true. However, you answered with `drop_duplicates` already, and this goes with OP’s train of thoughts.

Comment: @Datanovice You would probably have an issue with dimensions of the resulting dataframe (hence we use merge) or on the other hand, an inefficient operation because you would have to calculate the total value of each team, over and over again.

Comment: @QuangHoang sorry just went over the question again, this makes sense now, thanks mate.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang for your input - unfortunately this didn't work for me straight away. The problem was it needed an extra step of changing the pandas series generated by the groupby into a dataframe before merging. Much appreciated for your contribution. Always good to see different perspectives and would accept this as the main answer aswel if I could.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the method mentioned below. I hope this will help you.

```
NBAData=NBAData.groupby(["Player_name","Team"]).first()
```

Comment: This will only get you the first row from each group? How is it expected to answer the question?